# "To have it in someone" and "To have it in for someone"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> - I didn't know **I had it in me** to fly off the handle like that.
> - I might as well give in my notice; the boss **had it in for me** ever since I told him he was highly strung.

Please explain for me these phrases with some exemplifying sentences.
I find these confusing as these turned up in the book "Advanced Everyday English" .

Comment: FWIW, I have ***never*** heard the first one.

Comment: What [research](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-got-it-in-for?q=have+it+in+for) have you done? What are the example sentences you found in your book? Please help the community to help you.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Examples , (1) I didn't know I had it in me to fly off the handle like that. (2) I might as well give in my notice; the boss had it in for me ever since I told him he was highly strung.

Comment: I've edited the question for you. Please do take note about how to give the examples you're asking about. However, you do need to look things up in a dictionary too, and present that research as well. Here's [the other one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-got-it-in-one-to-do-something?q=have+it+in+one).

Comment: I'm closing this because both expressions are readily available in a dictionary.

Comment: Ah, the edit makes it a bit clearer, assuming that's what the OP meant, which is debatable. To have it in you is to be capable of something. If someone has it in for you, they're out to cause you grief.

Answer (score 1):

To *have it in for someone* means to wish that person harm.  From the book *[Stress Management and Prevention: Applications to Daily Life](https://books.google.com/books?id=v1DaykbsrtsC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=%22he%20had%20it%20in%20for%20me%22&source=bl&ots=jLUylMtM3i&sig=_jvxKGAgJ8-MeUEMnrwK-O5XyrU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFcQ6AEwDGoVChMIsIuijs-UyQIVhSQmCh26eQwa#v=onepage&q=%22he%20had%20it%20in%20for%20me%22&f=false)* by J Kottler and D Chen:

> If my boss looked at me funny, I thought he **had it in for me**.

To **have it in you** means to have the mental fortitude to do something, as in

> You say you'd like to kill your boss, but I don't think you **have it
>   in you** to kill anyone.

You could transpose this to the first person to describe yourself ("I don't **have it in me** to kill anyone) or to the third person to describe another party ("I don't think he **has it in him** to kill anyone."), but you wouldn't use the locution with *someone*.